# Выпуск видеочата №6 с @kizoso и @Ksenia 25.07.2018 в 11:57. Присоединяйтесь!

Tags: обсуждение, видеочат

С радостью спешу пригласить всех участников сообщества присоединиться к видеочату в среду, 25 июля 2018 года в 11:57 по московскому времени. Гостями шестого выпуска будут:

- [@kizoso](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/185637/kizoso). Екатерина на данный момент фрилансер, занимается версткой уже 6 лет. Летом катается на велосипеде. Три года назад она переехала из Сибири в Санкт–Петербург.
- [@Ksenia](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189882/ksenia). Ксения увлекается катанием на роликах, настольным теннисом и разработкой под Android. Основной язык Java.

@Ksenia и @kizoso активны на сайте, вместе они ответили на более чем 400 вопросов. Основные темы, в которых вы, возможно, встречали их: java, android, html, css. @Ksenia также крайне активно задает вопросы (их у нее почти 300!). В выпуске мы поговорим о сообществе, о программировании и о том, как живется девушкам в IT.

Видео будет доступно в реальном времени на канале сообщества: http://youtu.be/AKzDUfI0nms.

#### Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы гостям!

Как и ранее, главная цель видеочата – узнать друг друга поближе. Расскажите, гостям о том, что вам интересно в них! Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы участницам выпуска!

Ваши вопросы участницам выпуска вы можете задать в [чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Обязательно, задавая вопрос, упомяните `@NicolasChabanovsky` и/или имя участницы, кому вопрос адресован, чтобы я (мы) мог своевременно отреагировать на ваш вопрос. Также вы можете отправить ваш вопрос к участницам заранее мне на почту (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com) или опубликовать комментарием или ответом на данный вопрос.

С нетерпением ждем вас 25-го июля в 11:57!

Comment: а они живые? :-D ^_^

Comment: @Grundy Поясните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос?

Comment: Ну, настоящие? :-D Блин, я думал сегодня, а это еще 25го аж

Comment: @Grundy у Тебя будет возможность убедиться в этом самостоятельно, 25 числа

Comment: @Bald, [NSFW](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1-nyoxyp0c)

Comment: Почему  11:57? Не в 12, не в 11:55.

Comment: Почему вопросы можно задавать в общем чате, а не создать для этой цели новую комнату? Можно было бы посмотреть уже заданые и не повторяться.

Comment: @0xdb Помимо чата вопросы можно задавать прямо в комментариях к вопросу или в виде ответа. Как ранее показала практика, вопросов обычно набирается не так много, создавать отдельную комнату нет смысла.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, kizoso из Сибири откуда именно переехала?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Вопрос к kizoso: Занимаясь фрилансом, удаётся ли достичь более менее постоянного уровня заказов обеспечивающего финансовую независимость и стабильность. Если нет, то как последние достигаются?